# Django custom user model, cant login to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model which uses `phone number` as `username`.
but for some reason, I can't log in to the admin panel.

**Note**: I can create a `superuser` through CLI successfully. but when I try to log in it says: `Please enter the correct phone and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`

custom user model, `otp_auth_user.models.User`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Custom user model """
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    verification_code = models.CharField(default="",
                                         max_length=5)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

custom user manager, `otp_auth_user.models.UserManager`:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, phone, full_name, password=None, **extra_fields):

        validate_international_phonenumber(phone)
        
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("a phone number must be provided.")

        user = self.model(
            phone=phone,
            full_name=full_name,
            verification_code = generate_verification_code(),
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password):
        validate_international_phonenumber(phone)

        user = self.create_user(phone,
                                password)

  
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

user serializer class, `otp_auth_user.serializers.UserSerializer`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["id", "phone", "full_name"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "id": {"read_only": True}
        }
```

`Settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "otp_auth_user.User"
```

EDIT: When I try to check the superuser password via Django shell and I used the password that I used when creating a new superuser it returned `False` that's weird..., password is hashed and `user.check_password('admin')` is returning `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument of `create_user` method is `full_name`. So you are passing password as a full name in `create_superuser`:

```
def create_superuser(self, phone, password):
    validate_international_phonenumber(phone)

    user = self.create_user(phone,
                            password)
```

You should explicitly pass password:

```
def create_superuser(self, phone, password):
    validate_international_phonenumber(phone)

    user = self.create_user(phone=phone,
                            full_name=phone 
                            password=password)
```

After this you need to recreate superuser from CLI.